# Passing TMessage as a one-liner

Tags: c++builder, sendmessage, windows-messages

I use C++ Builder and I pass messages to window which are handled in `WndProc` to update user interface. Something like:

```cpp
struct TWmGuiUpdatedStruct
    {
    int id1;
    int id2;
    };

TWmGuiUpdatedStruct gui { 1, 2 };
    
TMessage msg;
msg.Message = WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED;
msg.WParam = WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED_MESSAGE_LIST;
msg.LParam = reinterpret_cast<NativeInt>(&guiparam);

// send to all forms in a loop
for (int i = 0; i < Screen->FormCount; i++) Screen->Forms[i]->Perform(msg.Message, msg.WParam, msg.LParam);
```

```cpp
// in WndProc
if (fMessage.Msg == WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED && msg.WParam == WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED_MESSAGE_LIST)
    {
    TWmGuiUpdatedStruct* gui = reinterpret_cast<TWmGuiUpdatedStruct*>(fMessage.LParam);
    // use gui->id1 and guid->id2 here...
    fMessage.Result = 0;
    return;
    }
TForm::WndProc(fMessage);
```

I find it over-complicated to initialize all in so many lines.

I need something simpler, like:

```cpp
TMessage msg { WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED, {WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED_MESSAGE_LIST,  reinterpret_cast<NativeInt>(&guiparam), 0} };
```

But it doesn't compile - it wants `System::Word` instead.

Is there a simpler way to initialize this to pass such GUI update messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [declaration](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Winapi.Messages.TMessage) of `TMessage`, it is a `struct` containing a `union` holding 2 `struct`s.

```cpp
struct DECLSPEC_DRECORD TMessage
{
public:
    unsigned Msg;
public:
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            System::Word WParamLo;
            System::Word WParamHi;
            System::Word LParamLo;
            System::Word LParamHi;
            System::Word ResultLo;
            System::Word ResultHi;
        };
        struct
        {
            NativeUInt WParam;
            NativeInt LParam;
            NativeInt Result;
        };
    };
};
```

Per cppreference, [Struct and union initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) explains that when dealing with a "nested initialization", you can only initialize the first member of a `union`, but you are trying to initialize the second member.

Since C++Builder does not support [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) at this time, you will have to do something like this instead:

```cpp
WPARAM wParam = WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED_MESSAGE_LIST;
LPARAM lParam = reinterpret_cast<NativeInt>(&guiparam);

TMessage msg { WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED, { { LOWORD(wParam), HIWORD(wParam), LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), 0, 0 } } };
```

With that said, I would suggest simply getting rid of the `TMessage` altogether, you don't actually need it:

```cpp
Screen->Forms[i]->Perform(WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED, WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED_MESSAGE_LIST, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&guiparam));
```

Otherwise, if you must use `TMessage`, then I would suggest creating a wrapper function to create a new `TMessage`, eg:

```cpp
TMessage MakeTMessage(unsigned Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TMessage msg;
    msg.Msg = Msg;
    msg.WParam = wParam;
    msg.LParam = lParam;
    msg.Result = 0;
    return msg;
}
```

And then call a control's `WindowProc()` instead of `Perform()`, eg:

```cpp
TMessage msg = MakeTMessage(WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED, WM_MY_GUI_UPDATED_MESSAGE_LIST, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&guiparam));
...
Screen->Forms[i]->WindowProc(msg);
```

Comment: Always a highly useful answer. Thank you!

Comment: Any particular reason why calling `WindowProc()` instead of `Perform()`? As I understand that `WindowProc()` is somehow more direct call. And are both synchronous meaning, they might not invalidate the pointer (like `SendMessage()`)?

Comment: All `Perform()` does internally is creates a `TMessage` and passes it to `WindowProc()`. So, if you already have a `TMessage`, you can just cut out the middle man